# Is there a way to change event parameters in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-selectable

I want to be able to change the parameters that are being passed into the selectable's start event, so I can basically allow my user to use the selectable jQuery UI effect without having to hold down the CTRL key.

JS

```
$(function() {
$( "#selectable" ).bind("mousedown", function(event, ui) {
    var result = $( "#select-result" ).empty();
    event.metaKey = event.ctrlKey = true;
});
$( "#selectable" ).selectable();
});
```

I have a fiddle with what I'm trying to accomplish here:

http://jsfiddle.net/josephbulger/ZfevM/

The problem I'm having, is that when i set the event's parameters in the start method, the stop method is not seeing the changes I'm making.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: If the chosen correct answer doesn't work for you, try this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30597419/4643607

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't set the properties here no...because it's a *different* `event` object in the `stop` method.  You can set some variables at a higher scope ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZfevM/2/)), but none that will persist on the `event` object.  It's not that it's "clearing" them really, it's just a brand spanking new object.

---

To make the selectable behave as if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is held down, bind to the `mousedown` event it uses ahead of time and set the `.metaKey` property on that [`event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to `true`, like this:

```
$("#selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable();
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZfevM/7/), remember to find *before* calling `.selectable()`, since event handlers are executed in the order bound.

Comment: @Nick so where is the higher scope that I need to tell the jQuery object to always use CTRL when a the user clicks on an item?

Comment: @Joseph - I added an example of this, just some variables in the scope that's the common parent, for example in the `document.ready` like you have...or even as `.data()` properties on the selectable container...wherever you want to put them really.

Comment: @Nick I see what you did, but that isn't causing the jQuery Selectable effect to use those values.  What I want it to do is to have the jQuery selectable object to actually "think" the user was holding down the CTRL key.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Joseph - Ah, that's a different question :) Yes you can bind the `mousedown` event ahead of time, like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZfevM/3/ Is that what you're after?

Comment: @Nick Perfect!! Can you add that fiddle to your answer so others can see what the solution was?

Answer (score 5):

I've updated the code. Have a look at this URL.

http://jsfiddle.net/phoenix_suresh/7f6j5/

Meanwhile, I've added ID attribute to

items so that you can have more control on it.

Answer (score 4):

After finding this answer I noticed that you can use the `originalEvent` property on the `event` object returned in the selectable `start` event handler to set the `ctrlKey` property to true.

Like so:

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        event.originalEvent.ctrlKey = true;
    }
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j1mz6v0g/1/)

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks!