# Disabling ctrl-click on jquery ui selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I was wondering if there is an option on the jQuery UI Selectable that will let me disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click, but still keep the draggable for the multiple selection. On my project I want to be able for people to select multiples, but only by dragging, not by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+clicking.

If there isn't, does anyone know a way I can achieve this?

Any information would be really helpful! :) Thanks!!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Selectable uses the metaKey flag to do multi-select, so you can bind metaKey to be false on the mousedown before calling selectable. Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click will always be off. Make sure to bind before calling selectable though.

```
$('#selectable').bind("mousedown", function (e) {
            e.metaKey = false;
 }).selectable()
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EvilAmarant7x/8eHkr/)

Comment: Thank You So Much!! :) I've been searching for this for days. hehe.

Comment: Just in case someone (like me) get's here and is trying to implement the opposite (allow multi select without ctrl) - do `e.metaKey = true;`

Answer (score 3):

There is another usage of this good solution above - if you want to be able to just use your mouse click to do all the selecting/unselecting, without the need for holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for multiselects or for unselects - just always set the e.metaKey from EvilAmarant7x's example to true. It was exactly what I needed.

Edit: apparently someone already thought of that: [Implement multiple selects with jQuery UI Selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396042/implement-multiple-selects-with-jquery-ui-selectable) :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#selectable").on("selectablestart", function (event, ui) {
event.originalEvent.ctrlKey = false;
});
```