# Disable ctrl+click selection in jQuery dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTables plugin: http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

By default users are able to select cells by holding the control key and clicking.

I would like to disable this functionality. There does not seem to be an option or api function for this.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this, preferably without modifying the original source?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5517930/1982680 check this if it can help you ! and please provide your code that you have done for dataTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a dataTables issue - it is a browser issue. There is *nothing* in jQuery dataTables
that provides this "feature". And to be more clear : It is a ***FireFox*** specific feature that do not exists in Chrome or Opera (for example).

Try open a FireFox, go to this page and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>click</kbd> on your own question above. Yes - the exact same thing happens!

If you programmatically want to disable this feature, see **https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/763547**.

Very simple, add `-moz-user-select: none` to elements you not want to be selected by <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>click</kbd> in FireFox. Here is an example :

```css
table.dataTable tbody th, table.dataTable tbody td {
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0o0h2ry7/**

...disables the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>click</kbd> feature in FireFox for a dataTable (1.10.x)

Comment: Thanks! I will test this out tomorrow! I feel like a moron if this is true :D